# Show real test coverage without 'Ignore' annotations in Istanbul

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, istanbul

Is it possible to show the actually code coverage with Istanbul, ignoring the *"ignore"* annotations?

e.g. Don't actually ignore next:

`/* istanbul ignore next */`

Our coverage reports 100% coverage but has ignores in the code.

Comment: So you want to simultaneously ignore and not ignore a segment of code? Sounds like the wrong approach.

Comment: It's more for recording the metric of what the real coverage is. Adding a lint rule against ignores might be a better approach to return the true coverage.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the HTML report to get a visual representation of the skipped statements? Might be able to subtract those to get the true coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a lint rule to prevent usage of `/* istanbul ignore ... */`, as you suggested in your comment, is probably the best solution.

However, as Istanbul is open source JavaScript software, you could also easily modify it, so that it ignores the `/* istanbul ignore ... */` statements. Here is a quick and dirty ad-hoc solution (the proper solution would be to fork the project, modify the source, build and install it):

1. Locate the Istanbul dependency or dependencies in your project's `node_modules` folder.
2. Search for `/^\s*istanbul\s+ignore\s+` in the identified folder(s), which is part of the regex pattern, that Istanbul uses to properly identify the ignore comments.
3. Modify the pattern in the found source file(s), e.g. change `istanbul` and/or `ignore` to some other terms, so that the existing `/* istanbul ignore ... */` comments in your project source code are no longer matched (or get rid of the entire mechanism, but that might be more difficult and riskier).

I do not recommend this approach. I just want to show, that it can be done. Depending on your specific setup, it may be easy or difficult to implement. I just tried it with an ES 2015 project in VS Code, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I realize it is not the answer you want to hear, though for me, it is the only logical answer: Remove these lines from your codebase.

Let me explain why:
The only function of these lines is to make sure the following line/statement is not included in the coverage results. So if you don't want it to be ignored, remove the lines.

If, for some reason, you really want to keep the lines in your codebase. You could consider a CI based solution.
Create a job that first removes all the lines you want to have removed.
Something like this:

```bash
for file in *.js
do
    sed '/istanbul ignore/d' "$file" > "$file".new_file.js
    mv "$file".new_file.js "$file".js
done
```

And then calculate the code coverage as you normally do.

Though, as this will change all files, it will be not ideal to run locally as you probably need to git-revert all changes afterwords. Therefore, I suggested CI, as there you can simply end the job and ignore the changes you made.

Comment: As an additional clarification: There seem to be some confusion around the internet that the line ignores the lines when running tests. But as you mention, this is not the case. The tests run normal for all the lines and, they are only ignored when calculating coverage (I know I just repeated what you say but I felt like this should be emphasized.